# How can I use Galleria in ReactJS

Tags: jquery, reactjs, galleria

I've been trying to create a photo gallery in my app, I added the starter code for Galleria in head of index.html

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/galleria/1.5.7/galleria.min.js"></script>`

of React project, but don't know how to do the rest